# PSQLException: ERROR: relation "TABLE_NAME" does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to run hibernate on a PostgreSQL 8.4.2 DB. Whenever I try to run a simple java code like:

```
List<User> users = service.findAllUsers();
```

I get the following error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: relation "TABLE_NAME" does not exist
```

Since I have option hibernate.show_sql option set to true, I can see that hibernate is trying to run the following SQL command:

```
    select this_.USERNAME as USERNAME0_0_, this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_0_ 
from "TABLE_NAME" this_
```

When in reality, it should at least run something like:

```
    select this_."USERNAME" as USERNAME0_0_, this_."PASSWORD" as PASSWORD0_0_ 
from "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" as this_
```

Does anyone know what changes I need to make for Hibernate to produce the right SQL for PostgreSQL?

I have set up the necessary postgreSQL datasource in applicationContext.xml file:

```
<!-- Use Spring annotations -->
 <context:annotation-config /> 
 <!-- postgreSQL datasource -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url"
   value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB_NAME:5432/SCHEMA_NAME" />
  <property name="username" value="postgres" />
  <property name="password" value="password" />
  <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
 </bean>
```

On the same file I have set up the session factory with PostgreSQL dialect:

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
 <bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.myPackage.dbEntities.domain.User</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>
 <!-- setup transaction manager -->
 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
   <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
  </property>
 </bean>
```

Finally, the way I am mapping the domain class to the table is:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "`TABLE_NAME`")
public class User {
@Id
@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;
```

Has anyone encountered a similar error?. Any help in solving this issue will be much appreciated. 
Please note that question is different to post [Cannot simply use PostgreSQL table name (”relation does not exist”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist)

Apologies for the lengthy post.

Comment: just to ask the obvious: does the user account accessing the database have permissions to view table TABLE_NAME? (if you have specified the schema in the connection it may not be wrong to omit the schema name from the hibernate select).

Comment: Yes, I on the table there is the following permission: ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" OWNER TO postgres;

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to specify the schema name in the Spring's Hibernate properties, not in the JDBC connection URL:

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SCHEMA_NAME</prop>
```

That said, your JDBC connection URL is in fact syntactically invalid. According to the [PostgreSQL JDBC documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/doc.html) you have to use one of the following syntaxes:

- `jdbc:postgresql:database`
- `jdbc:postgresql://host/database`
- `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database`

The `database` is here the database name. If the host is left away, it will default to `localhost`. If the port number is left away, it will just default to `5432`. Thus, one of the following is valid in your case:

- `jdbc:postgresql:DB_NAME`
- `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB_NAME`
- `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_NAME`

Comment: I'll try your solution straight away, BalusC. I assumed the connection URL was valid since I used it to test the connection to DB with the postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar driver and also in SQuirrel SQL Client.

Comment: If the prefix (in this case `jdbc:postgresql`) is valid, then the Driver will often not throw a `SQLException` for that, but the trailing part of your original URL is syntactically invalid. You shouldn't rely on the forgiveness of the drivers for that.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion for db URL connection and it seems to work. I now get a different type of error: PSQLException: ERROR: schema "schema_name" does not exist. And  hibernate created the following statement:select this_.USERNAME as USERNAME0_0_, this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_0_ from SCHEMA_NAME."TABLE_NAME" this_ . I can only assume that your suggested solution did indeed solve the problem and there is just another problem to solve.

Comment: Schema name is case sensitive and should not contain spaces or other special characters.

Comment: I am aware of schema being case sensitive. That's why I wonder why hibernate displays such error message but on actual SQL command it uses schema in upper case. Thanks for your help, though

Comment: Maybe you connected the wrong DB or the schema name is actually wrong (typo?).

Comment: No, I'm afraid that is the only DB on localhost, and the only schema on the DB. Thanks, nonetheless.

Comment: I have, that's where I got the schema name from. Thanks once again.

Comment: following the earlier comment I posted:"ERROR: schema "schema_name" does not exist", the reason why I got that was because schema was called SCHEMA_NAME (all in upper case) and hibernate would make the name lowercase. The way I got around it was to use BalusC suggested solution and to force hibernate to accept the upper case name. I added &quot; instead of the recommended ' sign: <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">&quot;SCHEMA_NAME&quot;</prop>. That finally solved the problem. I got the solution from https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=935715&p=2416841

Comment: In my `X.hbm.xml` file, I removed an invalid `class="..."` attribute from `<class name="com.mycompany.app.common.Stock" table="stock">` to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using spring-boot, set default schema in the configuration:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: my_schema
```

Make sure to include the schema name in the query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user_name FROM my_schema.users", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findAllNames();
```

Comment: My problem was that I used `jpa.properties.hibernate: default-schema` insted of `default_schema` (`default-schema` vs `default_schema`). `_`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the schema name in uppercase letters, I changed the schema name to lowercase letters.

In the entities I changed the mapping as follows

from
@Table(name="table_name", schema = "SCHEMA")
to
@Table(name="table_name", schema = "schema")

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation, it doesn't seem to support you adding the schema at the end of the connection url. Are you sure that's supposed to work?

A workaround would be to set the search_path in the database  to include your schema, but that would obviously fail if you have the same table in multiple schemas.

I don't know hibernate enough to comment on if it's possible to teach it about a schema.

Comment: Yes, I have tested the connection using postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar driver  and I did use that URL (jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB_NAME:5432/SCHEMA_NAME) to make a successful connection to the DB. I'll see how to use the search_path since I'm only using one schema in postgres.

Comment: Check again, the docs at http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/connect.html don't even mention schema.

Comment: Thank, Milen. BalusC pointed that out. I am new to postgres and although I have read the documentation, the connection url worked when testing the driver so I assumed it was correct. I now seem to have a different type of error.

Answer (score 1):

Due to using column definations I was getting this error

issue
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition ="user unique ID" )

solved
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about others but my case if worked only if I wrote my query like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT tbl.* FROM my_schema.my_table tbl", nativeQuery = true)
```

Always have some reference "tbl" for table and use it in the query.