# StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar only when deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I've created spring-boot application which uses jdbctemplate, everything works great on localhost but when i deploy my application to Heroku and visit the endpoint i'm getting this information :

```
StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT id, name, price, image, description FROM products;]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "products" does not exist Position: 49
```

If the SQL query is bad then how is that even possible that same application works local machine ?

Here's the method with jdbcTemplate i'm using:

```
public Products getProductsList() {
    ArrayList<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

    jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT id, name, price, image, description FROM public.products;",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Product(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getFloat("price"), rs.getString("image"), rs.getString("description"))
    ).forEach(product -> productsList.add(product));

    return new Products(productsList);
}
```

Comment: Either: 1) the table "products" does not exist in the deployed environment, 2) you have a typo in the table name (camel case, snake case, lowercase, uppercase) or if those are good, then this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753568/postgresql-tables-exists-but-getting-relation-does-not-exist-when-querying/36753702

Comment: like i said, it works on local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i repaired it.

Heroku added it's own configuration to my project for some reason(addon with postgresql) and it used database from settings->config vars -> DATABASE_URL instead of database from application.properties.

[I used command  from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30611910/9458550) in Heroku CLI to delete heroku database from my application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your schema name in your *application.properties* file like so :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

And write your query like so :

```sql
SELECT id, name, price, image, description FROM products;
```

Source : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034446/11466548) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24278772/11466548)

Comment: I am not using jpa/hibernate, just jdbctemplate

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to create the tables using a migration framework as described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps