# cannot get simple PostgreSQL insert to work

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I'm trying to do a simple insert into a postgres table, but am getting an error that the value I'm trying to insert is being interpreted as a column name

```
INSERT INTO "imageTagBusinessMainCategory"
(id, businessMainCategory)
VALUES
(DEFAULT, "auto dealer")
```

Where id is set up to be the primary key, and auto increment, and not null. Those are the boxes I ticked when I set up the table in phpPgAdmin.

I'm getting this error though:

```
ERROR: ERROR: column "auto dealer" does not exist
Query = INSERT
INTO "imageTagBusinessMainCategory"
(id, businessMainCategory)
VALUES
(DEFAULT,
"auto dealer")
```

I've put my table name in double quotes, as I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695312/1252748) I should.

And used `DEFAULT` to auto-increment the id as I've read [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2009-11/msg00103.php) I should.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: use single quotes for 'auto dealer'.

Comment: Single quotes. Leave off the id.

Comment: @muratgu that gives the error: `ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'imageTagBusinessMainCategory'"

 Position: 13`

Comment: @PaulTomblin how do you mean "leave off the id"? Thanks!

Comment: I mean like it shows in @Randy's answer. Except it looks like you need double quotes around the column name as well.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Use `'auto dealer'` instead. PostgreSQL interprets `"` as being quotes for identifiers, `'` as being quotes for strings.

Also:

- If this is a new project, just don't use mixed case tables; it is a
  source of frustration later. Instead of being able to use any case in
  your SQL statements, you must both quote the identifier name and get
  the case correct.
- There is no need to specify `id`/`DEFAULT`, you're
  asking it to do what it would have done already. I haven't met a DBMS
  that requires you to include `columnName`/`DEFAULT` if you want it to
  put the default value in the column, so I don't think this extra KV
  pair is going to make what is happening clearer to anyone reading
  your code later.

Comment: that gives me this error `ERROR: ERROR: column "businessmaincategory" of relation "imageTagBusinessMainCategory"
does not exist`

Comment: You probably created the column in mixed case, just like the table name. You must also quote the column name if this is the case. Stop using mixed case in naming, and you will save everyone a lot of pain.

Comment: @Matt I'm facing the same problem and trying to use pg with C++ is a pain when I have to type those double-quotes. Isn't there a workaround like some setting that would eliminate the need for these quotes?

Comment: @itsols Fist bullet of the "Also" would eliminate the need for the quotes; define your identities only using [a-z0-9] and don't specify them as having any particular case (define without quoting). Then you can refer to them however you want without quotes forever. If you or someone else decided that it was really important to have table names with spaces or in camel case, have fun quoting everywhere!

Comment: Point well taken Matt... I guess I've just got used to CamelCase in a way - it's been a long time (over 20 years)... Actually the trouble is not in double-quoting (yes, it would be easier without it), but the real pain is having to escape them in strings. I didn't see this coming until I put C++ and pg together. Thanks anyway for your inputs!

Answer (score 12):

```
INSERT INTO "imageTagBusinessMainCategory"
("businessMainCategory")
VALUES
('auto dealer')
```

EDIT: Added double-quotes around the column name

Comment: Hi, thanks. that gives this error: `ERROR: ERROR: column "businessmaincategory" of relation "imageTagBusinessMainCategory"
does not exist`

Comment: Sounds like you need to put the column name in double-quotes too. One reason why mixed-case table names in PostgreSQL are a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidFaber yeah, you're right. makes it a bit difficult to read though.. can i use dashes? ^^

Comment: @DavidFaber: personally I think identifiers that need quoting (e.g. mixed case) are a bad idea in *any* DBMS

Comment: Keep in mind that everywhere EXCEPT when creating the identifier, you can refer to it in mixed case and without quotes. So the table named `thishasareallylongname` could be accessed using `select * from thisHasAReallyLongName`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I agree with you. I don't even like mixed-case identifiers in SQL Server, which supports mixed-case table- and column-names.

Comment: @thomas, I would use underscores ('_') over dashes any day of the week for DB identifiers.

Comment: @thomas thanks, David. I decided to go with that as well. Cheers!

Comment: The whole idea of the hungarian notation or camel case was to increase readability of code (at least for me)... So using entirely lowercase field names is not a good option for me. I wish there's a good (I mean easy) way to get about this.

Answer (score 5):

Postgres, Oracle etc expect the column name to be in quotes if they have mixed case. So either create a convention of all small or all caps for your table columns or use quotes as David Faber suggested

```css
INSERT INTO "imageTagBusinessMainCategory"
("businessMainCategory")
VALUES
('auto dealer')
```

Answer (score 0):

On my case I had to change column name from camelCase `'isAdmin'` to snake_case `'is_admin'`.