# Select in postgresql using php

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I cant properly select some data in the database i made. I used postgresql.
The error says "Error in SQL query: ERROR: relation "book_flight.customer" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT idno FROM book_flight.customer ^"
I tried removing the book_flight, still doesn't work

here is the code:

```
<?php  

    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=AIRLINE user=postgres password=code");  
    echo 'Connected to: ', pg_dbname($db);

    $result = pg_query($db, "SELECT idno FROM book_flight.customer");
    if (!$result) {
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    } 

?>
```

table customer is in the schema named book_flight

Comment: Do you have a customer column ?

Comment: Can you show your table?

Comment: customer is the table

Comment: please ignore, cannot del comment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, sounds like names may be case sensitive.

[Cannot simply use PostgreSQL table name ("relation does not exist")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the database name, schema, and table name to small letters. It works. Seems that postgresql changes all to lower case and is case sensitive