# pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column doesnot exist

Tags: php, database, postgresql

i did follow the solution here : [Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594423/warning-pg-query-query-failed-error-syntax-error-at-or-near) but i still got the following error :

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "rosmoffi" does not exist LINE 1: ... FROM public."espece" where "espece"."Code_Espece" =Rosmoffi ^

this is my code :

```
$conn = pg_connect($conn_string);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM public."espece" where "espece"."Code_Espece" ='.$idd ;
if (!$result = pg_query($conn, $query)){
    echo  pg_result_error ($conn);
    return false;
}
$result = db($result); 
return $result;
```

Comment: Your $idd value is not quoted so it's assumed to be a column name. Use parameters, don't concatenate strings.

Comment: @NishantSolanki I did try it but i got the same error.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I don't know what do mean?

Comment: See my answer and read the documentation on parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM public."espece" where "espece"."Code_Espece" ='.$idd ;
```

Do not do this. If you were to output what you get here you'd see the error, as you should from the error message. Whatever is in the variable `$idd` will be put into the query as is and it will *not* be considered a string. It's just a part of the query. So since there are no quotes it will in this case be understood as a column name.

The worst part of this is that if `$idd` is coming from the user think what will happen when someone sets it to `1; truncate table espece`. Or something worse. **Learn how to use [parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) immediately.**

Using parameters your code would be:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM public."espece" where "espece"."Code_Espece" =$1';
if (!$result = pg_query_params($conn, $query, array($idd))){
```

This way the variable is given properly to the database and there is no injection vulnerability.

NB! For those who keep saying the double quotes should be removed, no. They should not. If the column name is capitalized as `Code_Espece` then PostgreSQL will not recognize it without the quotes. Capitalization is usually not recommended.

Comment: I did learn what you propose but i didn't know how to fix my error with this

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul By not concatenating the $idd to the SQL string but giving it via parameters. If you did that and got another error then update the question with the details.

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul I added the code example how it should be done

Comment: Warning: pg_query_params() expects parameter 3 to be array, string given in C:\wamp64\www\formdata1.php on line 21

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul You gave the parameters wrong. See my edited answer. The parameters must be in an array.

Comment: Ok i did try it but it send me this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp64\www\formdata1.php on line 21

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul Sorry, I was missing one parenthesis in the end