# PostgreSQL from supabase 'column "Description" of relation "Requests"' when trying to insert a row from javascript

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, supabase

I am trying to insert a row into a table named "Requests" through supabase

```
const { data, error } = await client
    .from('Requests')
    .insert( [
        { Name: 'Xyz', Email: 'Xyz@gmail.com', Type: 'ABC', Description: 'test test 123' },
    ])

console.log(data, error)
```

[The table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW4WY.png):

```
CREATE TABLE Requests (
    Rid         bigint,
    Name        varchar,
    Email       varchar,
    Type        varchar,
    Description varchar
)
```

but when the code is executed it gives this error:

```
{
    code: '42703',
    details: null,
    hint: null,
    message: 'column "Description" of relation "Requests" does not exist'
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist the problem might be because of how Postgres handles uppercase characters in column names and table-names.

Comment: i changed my table and column names to all lowercase and uppercase but still getting the same error

Comment: What happens when you trying inserting data through the Supabase Dashboard instead?

Comment: Couldnt quite figure out what the problem was but removing and than adding the table again made the api call work.

Answer (score 0):

You have the names of the columns in mixed casing. If you are going to be using that, you need to the put the names in ".
i.e.

```js
const { data, error } = await client
    .from('Requests')
    .insert( [
        { "Name": 'Xyz', "Email": 'Xyz@gmail.com', "Type": 'ABC', "Description": 'test test 123' },
    ])
```