Java Microservice (api gateway, config server, service registry and models)
I have a problem with packaging the application in docker. I run applications without the joker, everything is great, everything works, but it doesn't work with the docker. Error 500 on all requests. Our main public relations department of the new department issues such digitization:
"message": "JDBC exception when executing SQL [select d1_0.id ,d1_0.department code,d1_0.Description of the department,d1_0.department name from departments d1_0, where d1_0.department code=?] [ERROR: the relationship "departments" does not exist, position: 91] [out of stock]; SQL [out of stock]",
I looked at the logs, the error is AmqpConnectException.
I provide a link to my repository with the project:
https://github.com/IvanDolg/Production-practice-microservice -> select branch a here
and the repository for the configuration: https://github.com/IvanDolg/config-server-repo/blob/main/organization.properties
please help me, I can't figure out what's wrong. All services are visible on Eureka!
I tried a lot, changed the configuration for Docker-compose, but nothing

"exception when executing SQL .. the relationship "departments" does not exist" is not a simple docker problem, but sounds like the database is not configured with the schema required by the application. Compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist

As it currently stands, the question is way too broad. You should focus on a single microservice, probably in isolation (no gateway, config server or service registry) and try to make it work on Docker. This will also allow you to provide a [mre] inside the question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
